# Mysql connnector in python

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector

So here I am using mysql passwd param as a auth system. but since these functions are called into multiple files, I am asked about the password again and again.

I used the following code, it is called in 6 files and thats why when I run the main program, it asks me for password multiple times. is there any way to stop that with having the auth system?

```
import mysql.connector  # create database object


def libdb_connect_auth():
    try:
         inpt = input("Enter the password of the database:")  # auth system.
         libdb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd=inpt,
                                    database='lib', charset='utf8')

    except Exception as e:
        print("Connection error...", e)
    return libdb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a way that you can get password from one file each time like .env.

You can create constant file like .env in root level of project folder.
First time you can put the password from input and save this password inside .env file as key value pair.

After that you can get password from .env config file each time doing connections.

Comment: By that way anyone would have access to the password, I want the password to be an input from the user every time they log in.

Comment: You can set a logic of remove password from file during logout....